# Using another excel function in [Value if True] in IF function

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have tried to insert a formula in **[value if true]** in excel `IF` function, but for some reason its not working. Here is the formula I have used:

```
IF((AND(ISBLANK(J3),ISBLANK(U3)))=FALSE,=NETWORKDAYS(J3,U3)," ")
```

Comment: What is the error you get? I'm quite sure that the = before NETWORKDAYS is wrong.

Comment: i have removed that "=" and an extra bracket, it worked..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extra = and you don't need one of the sets of brackets (Extra brackets don't error but make it messy):

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(J3),ISBLANK(U3))=FALSE,NETWORKDAYS(J3,U3)," ")
```